# adView Error in: AdView adview=(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);

Tags: android

When I try to add AdMob this error appear. Lot of search but unable to solve this. kindly help me.

adView Error in: AdView adview=(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkVEx.jpg)

Comment: don't add images with code

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the adview in your layout.xml, which seems to be not present.

Add this is you layout.xml

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
                 android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_2_ad_unit_id"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                 />
```